# least common divisors

Tags: algorithm

What I am trying is write recursive function which returns the least common divisor or for example let's take 150 and 125, the greatest common divisor is 25 while the least common divisor is 5. Once again I need a recursive function in direct method it is trivial.

Comment: I would rather say 1 is the least common factor.

Comment: no 1 not  i meant all number >1

Comment: c = gcd(a, b)
what_you_are_looking_for = a/c

Comment: @getekha - gcd(150, 125) = 25. 150 / 25 = 6. 6 is not a divisor of 125.

Comment: Show some effort and we'll help. We won't just do your homework for you.

Comment: @IVlad my bad: it should be min(a,b)/c

Comment: @getekha: gcd(7, 14) = 7. 7 / 7 = 1, and the OP wants it to be > 1. gcd(12, 14) = 2. 12 / 2 = 6, which also doesn't work. It's not that easy

Comment: @davit-datuashvili: All the common divisors will divide into the GCD. Hence if you want the smallest common divisor that is greater than 1, that means you want the smallest prime that divides into the GCD. If this is your goal then you should consider asking a different, more focused, question, perhaps on mathoverflow?

Finding the GCD is a very well established, and simple, algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm

Comment: @IVlad You're right I'm wrong :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test every number until `sqrt(min(a, b))`: if the numbers are both divisible by it, you found it. You can only test primes if you want.

If you haven't found any such number, then check if the other number is a multiple of the minimum: if yes, the minimum of the two is the solution. Otherwise, there's no solution.

You can do better. You can go only up to `sqrt(gcd(a, b))`. That should be fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find the `least common factor` of an array elements, you can first compute the `GCD` of all the elements and then find the `least prime factor` of the `GCD` obtained...

to get the gcd of all array elements:-

```
g=arr[0];
for(i=1;i<arr.length();i++)
   g=gcd(g,arr[i]);
```

now, to get the least prime factor loop till `sqrt(g)`

```
for(i=2;i<=sqrt(g);i++)
  if(g%i==0)
    return g
```

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation:
Above solution will not work for this numbers 5 and 10 where least common divisor is 5
so taking square root wont work here

```
from math import gcd
def leastCommonPrimeDivisor(a, b):
    g=gcd(a,b)  # gcd of a and b
    for i in range(2,g+1):
        if g%i==0:
            return i # returns least common divisor
    return -1
```